# React useState with default array value does not rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, rerender

If I use a number or string as default value, it rerenders the app after use of setVotes just like with setSelected. With array it does not work (only would display real renewed array after page is rerendered, as it is easy to check with setSelected button)

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [votes, setVotes] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0])
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const handlenext = () => {
    setSelected(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))
  }
  const handlevote = () => {
    let newvotes=votes
    newvotes[selected]+=1
    setVotes(newvotes)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handlenext}> next anecdot</button>
      <p>{props.anecdotes[selected]}</p>
      <button onClick={handlevote}> vote</button>
      <p>votes {votes[selected]}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const anecdotes = [
  'I',
  's',
  'T',
  'A',
  'l',
  '.'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
 const handlevote = () => {
    let newvotes= [...votes]
    newvotes[selected]+=1
    setVotes(newvotes)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need go build a new array. Do not use old array. Should you const a=[…b]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a new reference. Arrays and object are reference based, if you don't create a new one is the same reference and react don't go deep to compare differrence. Besides you are mutating state directly which is bad.

Create a new copy from the state as `const newvotes= [... votes]`. Now you can pass next state without mutating the original and passing a new reference as well